# What is the oldest supported iOS version I can submit to appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I'm trying to find the oldest supported version for an iOS App.
I only found that beginning 27. march 2019 they have to be rebuild with 12.1 SDK https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03202019a 
 In latest Xcode with 12.1 SDK included I can choose target version back to iOS 8.0 
Does this mean I can still upload iOS 8 apps to the AppStore?

Comment: Yes, or more accurately, you can release an app that will support devices running iOS 8. But it further back you choose to support, the more work for you, avoiding (or only conditionally supporting) features in new iOS versions, runtime checking for deprecated API, etc. The common middle-of-the-road balance that we often strike is to choose to support one major version back (e.g. now that we have iOS 12, use target of iOS 11, unless we desperately need to support older devices).

Comment: Thank you @Rob I'm aware of the consequences :(

Comment: For iPhone that last two major version have most of the users. However there are a lot of old iPads still around. So for iPads I'd say go back to iOS 10 or even 9.